# Fix the version conflict (google-services plugin)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the Firebase versions to the latest

> Note : Latest firebase version is 15

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using this for ionic/cordova, Please follow below steps.
   Remove android platform
   on FCMPlugin.gradle (plugin folder) edit like this:

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'

Then on plugin.xml file

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4" />
```

2. If you are not using for cordova, please make sure you are using latest library for firebase.