# Version conflict in gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is pathetic.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1' // Error
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

This line `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'` is causing error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.1.

Is it from Google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259897/fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin/50260087#50260087

Comment: please add your project level gradle

Comment: i think adding classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' in your project level gradle will solve your probelm

Answer (score 0):

Update the google play services gradle plugin version:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

Comment: I have this problem too.
I already use services 3.3.1 and I still get the error.
Sometimes it works, but when I add a completely unrelated library (eg. compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.22.5') it stops working and throws the exception again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you apply the plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of your gradle build/app file.

And not (also) at the top. 
In my case the firebase-plugin crashed, but was kind enough to apply the plugin at the top of the file...